# How to put Apache website to 503 "temporary down"?

Tags: apache, http, configuration

RFC2616, 503 Service Unavailable

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or **maintenance of the server**

How to configure Apache 2.2 to serve particular name based virtualhost 503 code with custom HTML page?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule !^/down/for/maintenance$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}down/for/maintenance [L,R=503]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive makes sure that no additional internal error occurs when redirecting to a custom error document.

Comment: Great, but how to specify custom "maintenance" page?

Comment: ErrorDocument 503 /down/for/maintenance/index.html

Comment: My error document refers to static content on file system so am getting 503 for static content its refereeing like `11.11.11.11 - - [15/Mar/2016:13:24:31 -0500] "GET /core/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 503 1985` how do I make sure my error document can load static content without getting 503

Comment: @RanPaul You can extend the `RewriteRule` pattern or add a `RewriteCond` directive to match these URLs as well. For example: `RewriteRule !(^/down/for/maintenance$|^/core/css/) …`

Comment: It always redirects to maintenance page

Answer (score 54):

### 503 Temporarily Unavailable, with trigger

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteCond "/srv/www/example.com/maintenance.trigger" -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=503,L]
```

If the `maintenance.trigger` file exists, Apache will serve up a `503 Service Unavailable` response. To serve up a custom "down for maintenance" page, use `ErrorDocument` to specify the file, like so:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503_with_cats.html
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Does the constant checking of a file not slow down a request?

Comment: Good question! I haven't done any benchmarks. Am assuming the OS filesystem cache keeps things speedy.

Comment: It is misleading to specify the target part in rewrite rule, I prefer:
`RewriteRule ^ - [R=503,L]`

Answer (score 0):

@temoto

To specify a 503 for bots and a maintenance page for humans, try the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#for bots such as google
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Googlebot|Googlebot|Mediapartners|Adsbot|Feedfetcher|bingbot)-?(Google|Image)? [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule !^/down/for/maintenance$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}down/for/maintenance [L,R=503]

#for humans
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1\.1\.1\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maint.html [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maint.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: why use a separate page for humans? 503 pages can contain content, and browsers will display it.

Comment: In some cases, tomcat may not be able to serve a 503 page. Thus, we let Apache serve a static page.

Comment: But this page doesn't have to be different for humans and bots... that difference doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @AlexanderN why would you be less friendly to bots?

Comment: @Calimo By friendly one can think of an elegant page instructing a user to update their bookmarks etc, a bot simply needs the corresponding HTTP code.

Comment: @AlexanderN you can send the instructions to the bot as well, what's the problem with that? Anyway you're doing it already (except Google and a handful others) as your regex doesn't catch all bots.