# Is that possible to configure Websphere to response with 503 when web application is down?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications, websphere

My web application is hosted in IBM Websphere application server. What I need is to response with status 503 when the web application is down. I noticed 404 is returned by default. Is there any way to change this behaviour? One more piece of explanation: I MUST return 503 regardless of how ridiculous is that idea, that's requirement of huge legacy system.

Comment: Not sure if and how WebSphere can do that, but you wouldn't have a web server like Apache/IHS (or something else) in front of WebSphere that can do that for you?

Comment: By down do you mean stopped?

Comment: Yes, down == stopped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a developer question but an operations question.

Answer (score -1):

Do you talk directly to the application server?  Then this 404 is not returned by anything, it's your browser's default behavior on an unreachable page.

If you have an HTTP server (and you should!), then it is there where you should take care of this.  The Was plugin will detect the server is down and the HTTPD software will take care of this.

In Apache you could work on something like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =404
 RewriteRule !^/down/for/maintenance$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}down/for/maintenance [L,R=503]
```

(from [How to put Apache website to 503 "temporary down"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622466/how-to-put-apache-website-to-503-temporary-down))